# How to check if display over other apps feature is available in the android phone or not

Tags: android, android-background

There are certain devices which runs on android 10 go edition, they do not have this feature only.
Now how to check if this is available or not to take different decision?

Comment: Do you want found you code only run in android 10??

Comment: yeah it seems there are restriction on android 10 and above
so for android 10 and above.

Comment: Why not use it 'if and else '?